# docker: command not found in bash script but can use docker in bash

Tags: bash, git, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using bash on windows server 2019, and trying to run a simple bash script, but when it gets to this line:

```
# check if containers are running, and stop them if they are not for the current project
all_up_ids=$(docker ps -q);
```

I get a 'docker docker command not found' error. Oddly I can run docker and docker-compose in bash no problem. I have set my environment variables. The only way I was able to get docker commands to work in bash was to put this in my .bashrc file

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin"
alias docker=docker.exe
alias docker-compose=docker-compose.exe
```

Is it possible something is still wrong with my environment setup? Any assistance is appreciated.

Docker  Info:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        2ee0c57608
 Built:             11/13/2019 08:00:16
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       2ee0c57608
  Built:            11/13/2019 07:58:51
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1588#issuecomment-449421977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.bashrc` script is being executed only for interactive terminals, that means every time you open a terminal window, `~/.bashrc` gets executed in that session. So anything defined there won't be available for scripts, because they're being executed in a non-interactive mode.

I would rather put your configuration into `~/.bash_profile`. That script gets executed only once when you open a login shell, so when you log in and start a script, it will be available for that script also.

Comment: oh, how would I make this available to the script? Or am I just approaching this all wrong? Complete noob to bash.

Comment: I'm using git bash, so when you say login, is there something extra I have to do?

Comment: No, in that case every new Git bash terminal you open is a login shell so `~/.bash_profile` is always being executed during the shell startup.

Comment: So I added this to my ~/.bash_profile and restarted the shell, I'm still getting the error, I even tried a simpler statement in the script:  docker version
No luck

Comment: @AustinJones Are you executing your script through bash?

Comment: That says nothing about how the script is being executed. Important part is what you have in shebang. If it's `#!/bin/sh` then it's being executed by `sh` (or `bash` in `sh` compatible mode) and `~/.bash_profile` is not being executed. And if you don't have any shebang at all in your script, then `#!/bin/sh` is being used.

Comment: are you referring to #!/bin/bash 
this is the first line in the script

Comment: oh what would be the proper shebang to execute ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Well, to process bash's configuration files, you need `bash` to execute it, so you need to have `bash` in rhe shebang.

Comment: I was able to solve it by setting the docker path in the script, and expanding aliases

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly related (not Ubuntu), but has the same error message
Just in case ...on RHEL `docker` can be installed as `podman-docker`:

```
sudo dnf install podman-docker
```